# Github secrets cannot be included into Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, environment-variables, github-actions

Here is my workflow file

```python3
 jobs:
    build:

    runs-on:    windows-latest
    environment: Main
    env: 
      MAINAPI: ${{secrets.MAINAPI }}
      TESTAPI: ${{secrets.TESTAPI }}
      BRAINID: ${{secrets.BRAINID }}
      BRAINKEY: ${{secrets.BRAINKEY }}

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install flake8 pytest
        python -m pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
        pip install -r requirements.txt --no-deps
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pytest
      env: 
        MAINAPI: ${{secrets.MAINAPI }}
        TESTAPI: ${{secrets.TESTAPI }}
        BRAINID: ${{secrets.BRAINID }}
        BRAINKEY: ${{secrets.BRAINKEY }}
```

Here is my code

```py
    mainapi = str(os.environ["MAINAPI"])
    apiurl = str(os.environ["TESTAPI"])
```

I have set the secrets as Environment secrets, repository sercrets and even as an environment. However, none of them seems to work. Pls help

Comment: Why are you installing the Python 3.11 version of PyAudio when your test environment is 3.10?

Comment: I changed it now but the problem is still there

Comment: Have you actually correctly set those secrets as documented here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets? Also, the `str()` in your Python code isn't needed since the value of environment variables are always, by definition, strings. Which makes me think you are engaging in ["Cargo Cult Programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). In which case you really should have told us where you got the idea that doing `str(os.environ["ENV_VAR_NAME"])` was necessary.

Comment: Actually, the value of the environment variable was being returned as None and thus couldn't be concatenated as I had to join another string with the variable later in my program. Only after adding `str()` it became clear that the environment variable was not being passed to the program. Before I started using Github actions, I did not use `str()`.       
Btw, I followed the docs while making the secrets.